# JPA mapping file

Tags: jpa

Suppose that there are 2 entities:

```
public class A { 
    int id;
    B b;
}
```

And

```
public class B { 
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

When retrieving an object of type A I want the field b to have only the id populated (so b.name will not be set). Is it possible to specify this in the JPA mapping file (for example in a one-to-one element) ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you're working in a client/server and don't want the client to see the field, then using @JsonIgnore (if JSON) or @XmlTransient (if JAXB) to stop the serialization would be the best way. If field b is a large field that you normally do not need, then use fetch = FetchType.LAZY, and do a fetch join whenever you actually need the field.